# Operator $T$ with $T^2=T$ which is not a projection

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

Can someone help me with this exercise? I know that if $T$ is a bounded
 self-adjoin operator with $T^2=T$ then it is a projection. I need an example of an operator with $T^2=T$ which is not a projection (not self-adjoint, of course)

Comment: You need to precise orthogonal projection. A linear transformation such that $P^2=P$ is by definition a [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: that's not the case in many branches of functional analysis (which where this question is tagged). One reserves "projection" for orthogonal projection, and uses "idempotent" when only $P^2=P$ is wanted.

Comment: A general projection corresponds to a direct sum decomposition of a vector space $V=X\oplus Y$, where $T=I$ on $X$ and $=0$ on $Y$. If you have an inner product space, then $T$ is selfadjoint iff $X \perp Y$.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that your projections are orthogonal projections. You can take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}T\colon&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&(x+y,0).\end{array}$$It is a projection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. But it is not orthogonal with respect to the usual inner product.

Answer (score 1):

This example may fit the case. Let P be an operator in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ written in the form
\begin{pmatrix}
I&X\\
0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
where $I$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mbox{ran}\, P$, the range of $P$, and $X$ can be any bounded linear operator from $(\mbox{ran}\, P)^{\perp}$ into $\mbox{ran}\, P$.

In general, given an orthogonal projection $E$, and an invertible operator $X$, not unitary, in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, then $XEX^{-1}$ is what you want.